# How to move selected image to front using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

*Scenario: I have tons of images in a single worksheet，and many of them are overlapping with each other.*

**How can I write a *VBA* code so when user click on any image in that worksheet and *Excel* will automatically bring that image to the front?**

Comment: There are two questions here. 1) how do I run code when I click an image, and 2) how do I let code move the selected object to the front. Which of these two questions did you intend to ask - or do you need help with both.

Comment: the thing I want is that when user selected an image (which that picture has been surrounded by 8 tiny white circle), VBA just move it to the front. is it possible to do? btw To Floris: I dunno why I received an error message when I try to run the connect_all(), it says error 438, object doesnt support this property or method.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? Do you have any shapes other than images in your sheet? Are there any groups? Try my code on a new worksheet with just two overlapping pictures - see if that works.

Comment: Yes I did what you said, I removed all objects beside 2 pics in a brand new worksheet but it still dont work... I am using Excel 2003.

Comment: Oh dear - I can't test with 2003 and I know lots of things changed… Actually - what I intended to say was "create a new file, then put two images in it". That is not the same thing as (thinking you are) removing all but two objects… Can you manually assign the macro to the two images? This involves right clicking the image, then assigning the macro `picture_click`. If that works, then record your actions (with the macro recorder) and see what VBA code it returns. It looks like `OnAction` is a valid property - even in 2003. So I'm not quite sure why you are running into a problem.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I manually assigned macro into 2 images and it do move image to the front when I clicked the picture. However, it requires user to "click" in order to trigger the marco. that is kind inconvenient for user who try to move the picture which is not overlapping with other pictures. btw I dont quite understand what do you mean "It looks like OnAction is a valid property"?

Comment: How is selecting and clicking not the same thing for you? You specifically asked "and when user click on that image"... In other words - how is clicking "inconvenient"? Are you saying you want to be able to drag the images around as well? As for my "`OnAction` is valid" comment: I was wondering whether this might not be a mechanism that exists in 2003, but apparently it does.

Comment: oh yes. in my case clicking is different than selecting, because if user clicked a picture, it moves to front, but if user want to move that picture around than he needs to click that picture again in order to do so.

Answer (score 5):

If you have an object `myObject` that you want to bring to the front you use

```
myObject.ShapeRange.Zorder msoBringToFront
```

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa213680(v=office.11).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa213680%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

Your object might for example be the selection:

```
set myObject = Selection
```

As for responding to a click - that's trickier. There doesn't appear to be an event for "selecting a picture" . But there *is* a solution...

You can make a single macro called `Picture_click()`, and assign that macro to each picture. There doesn't appear to be an event-driven way to achieve this, but the following works:

Add the following to a module:

```
Sub picture_click()
  ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Select
  Selection.ShapeRange.ZOrder (msoBringToFront)
End Sub

Sub connect_all()
Dim sh As Shape
For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
  sh.OnAction = "picture_click"
Next sh
End Sub
```

You have to run the `connect_all` sub just once, to assign the `picture_click` macro to each shape. Now, when you click a picture (or other shape) it comes to the front.

Note - the `Application.Caller` tells you what object was clicked - in other words, what caused the call to `picture_click`. This is necessary because the "click" doesn't cause the picture to be selected yet - that happens *after* the macro has run. So you can't just use the selection. Tricky, that.

I referenced [this earlier post](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2003-customize/need-to-obtain-picture-name-in-vba-code-when/cc31ad88-147d-4337-aa90-587733d7b684) to come up with this solution - specifically, RichJ's solution.

**afterthought**

If you don't want the picture to be selected after you clicked it, you can modify the `picture_click()` sub to the following:

```
Sub picture_click()
  ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).ZOrder msoBringToFront
End Sub
```

This will move the picture to the front but doesn't select it. There is something to be said for that approach.

Answer (score 0):

With every shape, assign the `BringToFront` macro, then put the following in a module

```
Sub BrintToFront

Selection.ShapeRange.ZOrder msoBringToFront

end sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately when you click a picture that doesn't make it the `Selection` by the time the macro is called.

Answer (score 0):

Assign this macro to all Shapes:

```
Sub lux()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).ZOrder msoBringToFront
End Sub
```

Comment: `msoBringForward` only moves forward by 1. You need `msoBringToFront` to be ahead of all the other images.